# Reconcile Rows using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to set up a process to reconcile a table based on specific constraints. (SQL Server)

Table contains the following cols,

```
Start Time
End Time
Status
Hours
Note
```

My logic is the following

```
starting at row 2
if Start Time(row 2) = End time( row 1 ) and status(row2)=status(row1)
then
hours = hours(row1)+hours(2)
move to next row
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated on how I should approach this problem.

Thanks

Comment: What is your RDBMs? The solution may be different from one to another. Also, what was your attempt to solve it? Remember, SO is not a free service code.

Comment: Looks like a very basic SQL query - could be `SUM() -- GROUP BY...` or `SUM () OVER (PARTITION BY .. ORDER BY)` . But without a table with example data I could not tell. Add an example input table with data for all columns (except `Note`), with cases where end time is equal to next row's start time and cases where this is not true - and an example output data table. I think ~10 input rows should be enough.

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but the following should contain the elements that should help you achieve what you really want (please, edit the question like already suggested):

**Setup**

```
-- drop table DatesAndTimes
create table DatesAndTimes
(
    RowNo INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    StartTime DATETIME2,
    EndTime DATETIME2,
    Status INT,
    Hours INT
)
GO

insert into DatesAndTimes (StartTime, EndTime, Status, Hours) VALUES 
    ('20170101', '20170102', 1, 5), 
    ('20170102', '20170103', 1, 6),
    ('20170104', '20170105', 2, 4),
    ('20170105', '20170107', 2, 3),
    ('20170110', '20170111', 3, 2)
```

**Test**

```
select * from DatesAndTimes

begin tran
;with cte as ( 
    select TOP 100 PERCENT RowNo, StartTime, EndTime, Status, Hours, 
        LAG(EndTime) OVER (ORDER BY RowNo) PrevEndTime,  
        LAG(Status) OVER (ORDER BY RowNo) PrevStatus,
        LAG(Hours) OVER (ORDER BY RowNo) PrevHours
    from DatesAndTimes
    order by RowNo
)
update Dest
SET Dest.Hours = (
        CASE WHEN C.StartTime = C.PrevEndTime AND C.Status = C.PrevStatus THEN C.Hours + C.PrevHours 
        ELSE C.Hours 
    END)
from cte AS C
    join DatesAndTimes Dest ON Dest.RowNo = C.RowNo

select * from DatesAndTimes
rollback
```

- `begin tran.. rollback` are placed because I do not to actually update initial data in the table. They should be dropped when really doing the update.
- `LAG` is a SQL Server 2012+ function that allows to access values from "behind" (or after, if a negative offset is used as input).
- `TOP 100 PERCENT .. ORDER BY` is put to ensure the order of UPDATE. Although it usually happens using the clustered index or insert order of records, it is not guaranteed. Not really it is the most clever way to order (order not allowed in CTE, looks like a hack to me).